# Process object does not works in Mono

Tags: bash, mono

I tried to run a simple command escaped but get no response, no output buffer, but if I delete the "$" symbol works well. What do I do?

```
public class Executor
{
    private Process proc;

    public Executor ()
    {
        this.proc = new Process();
        this.proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        this.proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        this.proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        this.proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    }

    public String call(String command){
        this.proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
        this.proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c $'" + stringToHexEscape(command) + "'";

        this.proc.Start();
        String result = this.proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ();
        this.proc.WaitForExit();
        this.proc.Close ();

        return result;
    }

    public String stringToHexEscape(String buffer){
        byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(buffer);
        String hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (hexString))
            return "";
        return ("\\x" + hexString.Replace("-", "\\x")).Trim();
    }
}
```

In the command try:

```
Executor executor = new Executor ();
String result = this.executor.call (
    "[ -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ] && echo \"Found\" || echo \"Not found\""
);
Console.WriteLine("stdout: {0}", result);
```

But the result is empty string. From bash works fine:

```
me@Unknow:~$ /bin/bash -c $'echo \x61'
a
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for edited question:**

The core issue at hand is subprocess I/O std/err redirection to the parent process. This can be seen via `UseShellExecute` if you set it to true:

```
Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
```

You will be able to do want you are trying to 'execute' but really you are doing a bash evaluation using built-ins. Of course you can not use shell redirection in this case as that is just not possible with the `Process` class. Create a console test app that uses `UseShellExecute = true` with no redirection and you will see your evaluations work as expected, now you just need to capture that output.

There are **many** ways around this and many use `BASHISM` techniques such as using `coproc` and/or other child-process output redirection (i.e. using `exec` to create another output and redirecting child output.) Which way is better? ... If you do this constantly within your app, some would say to use a posix shell that does not do sub-process substitution like `dash`... but again, personal preference.

This is a `pipe` technique that I have used many times as I do not have to change (hack up) my bash evaluation strings, just redirect some (or all) of the output that I am interested in capturing.

BTW: Maybe I'm missing something. As far as preventing `injections`, anyone with process permissions can `strace` any system call including these and thus watch your shell/bash calls, and via `gdb` do code injections into those processes...

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace consoleEcho
{
    class MainClass
    {
        [DllImport ("libc")]
        private static extern int system (string exec);

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start ("mkfifo", "/tmp/fifo");

            system (" [ -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ] && echo 'Found' >/tmp/foobar || echo 'Not found' >/tmp/foobar ");

            var proc = new Process ();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cat";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/tmp/foobar";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();
            String result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close ();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Process.Start ("rm", "/tmp/fifo");
        }
    }
}
```

**Shell output:**

```
Not found
```

*(My ssh files are not located in the standard locations...)*

**Original before question update:**

You are starting a new bash/shell interpreter when you are already going to be in one, i.e.:

```
bash -c echo -e '\x61'
```

or

```
bash -c echo $'\x61'
```

Both return an empty string when run from bash's CLI.

**Skip starting a second interpreter and call echo directly:**

```
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "echo";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " '\x61' ";
```

**Cut/Paste example:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace consoleEcho
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "echo";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " '\x61' ";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();
            var output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ();
            Console.WriteLine("stdout: {0}", output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is: have onle 1 line to execute, example this.execshell("[ -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ] && echo \"Found\" || echo \"Not found\"") and parse in hexadecimal to prevent injections: proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c $'" + stringToHexEscape(command) + "'";

Comment: Can you update your question to include what you are actually trying to do as your example is being lost in the comment formatting... ;-)